# Checking existing vim install's configuration options

Tags: vim

I'm about to reinstall vim, and I want to find out what options the current install was configured with when it was built.  Is there any way to do this by passing vim an argument or executing some special Ex command like "show-config-options" or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `vim --version` will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks... I saw that but was hoping for something with the exact configure commands, rather than just a list of which features were included.  Oh well. :)

Comment: @dirtside - if you're looking to see what options are set *within vim*, try ":set". If that still isn't what you're looking for, then you'll have to explain a little better what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Like rmeador said, or possibly easier to yank/paste:

```
:version
```